# Are we feeling 1g or 2g?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram

I know the acceleration by gravity is 1g, but what about the force of the floor exerting on us? is like if we replace the floor with a propulsed object going at 1g, Wouldn't the 1g of the floor or propulsed object + 1g of gravity make us feel 2g?

Comment: First, they are in opposite directions so you should be wondering why they don't cancel out so that you feel nothing at all, not why they double. Second, you do not feel any forces in free fall so you do not feel the 1G down. WHen you wonder why they don't double, you might be mistaking acceleration for force. Are you imagining being in between two presses each exerting x Newtons on your body from opposite directions? Even in that case you don't feel 2x Newtons. You only feel x Newtons.

Comment: And it doesn't make sense to say the presses exert any number of gs inwards either because it is an acceleration. So if that is your mental picture that of presses exerting gs, then that doesn't make sense. You can experience and exert forces, but you only experience accelerations (you do not exert accelerations).

Comment: @DKNguyen I know two forces with opposite directions cancel each other, but an object between them would feel the two forces.

Comment: Consider this. If you have a press where the left press and the right press are exerting 1N of force inwards would you say you are feeling 1N? Or 2N? If you think 2N, then think about how is that is different than a 1N press pushing you against a static wall. (Hint, it's not because the wall provides an equal and opposite reaction of 1N as well). That's what I mean if that was your mental picture. I didn't mean that you would feel no forces. If that was not your mental picture then disregard what I said.

Comment: @DKNguyen Using your example of press, imagine the left press is exerting 1N to an object but this object only it's inertial mass force is acting in oposite direction which means there is no other force in oposite to the left press that is acting on the object. Then we have another case in which there is a right press also exerting 1N, so Would the two cases be equal?

Comment: That's a good question. The motion would obviously not be equal since one would be zero acceleration and the other would be accelerating. I'm not 100% on this, but I think what you would feel a pressure equivalent to 1N distributed the side of your body whereever a press was present. Also, in the case where there is only the left press where you were also accelerating, the right side of your body would feel its own weight due to the acceleration. Might be worth another SE question.

Answer (score 3):

It is only the 1 g acceleration from the floor that we feel. We don’t feel gravity itself.

For example, in the ISS gravity is still about 90% as strong as on the surface of earth. Nonetheless, because the acceleration from the floor is removed the astronauts feel as though gravity is absent.

Comment: That's according to relativistics and if gravity is not a force but if gravity is indeed a force then we feel 2g.

Comment: @Y-9b8z In conversations like this, I think it would behoove you to refer to the acceleration of gravity and the force of gravity rather than just using "gravity" and having it mean whatever you want it to mean from moment to moment. And reserving the lone term "gravity" for the phenomena of gravity itself. Otherwise it gets confusing.

Comment: @Y-9b8z no, my answer applies to both Newtonian mechanics and GR (and probably most alternative theories too)

Comment: @Y-9b8z, Astronauts on board the space station feel weightless. That's not "according to relativistics," It's a simple fact. You can see it in the videos that they shoot there, or if you are a multi-billionaire, you can buy a ride up to the ISS to find out for yourself. At the same time, those astronauts are deep within Earth's gravitational field. That's not "according to relativistics" either. That's according to good old Issac Newton.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Sorry, i still don't understand why an object that acts on it two forces with opposite directions would be the same as if only one of them is acting on it.

Comment: @Dale Explain why if gravity is a force the effects ( weight for example ) would be the same as if it's not a force.

Comment: @Y-9b8z that is too big for comments. Please ask a new question on that topic. In a nutshell that holds for any theory of gravity that respects the equivalence principle

Answer (score 2):

You do not feel the 1g downard of gravity. The reason is that your body can only sense pressures and accelerations relative to itself and if 1g is applied equally to your entire body (or equally enough that it is below your threshold of sensation, like on Earth but not near a small blackhole or neutron star with very high gravitational gradient), then you feel nothing because there's no relative difference. In other words, your body (and objects general) experience forces  and pressures through strain and stress of the material. No strain or stress means no detectable internal force. This is why you feel nothing in free fall even though a force is being applied to you and you are accelerating.

You do, however, feel the 1g on your feet applied by the ground because of the compression (which is a form of strain).